# Capture mouse events inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have seen lot of post on "Capture mouse events inside an iframe"  have the same problem

I have a html page called test1.html and i have an iframe in it which is basically a website (e.g. google.com, yahoo.com etc). Now i would like to store / display the data which has been highlighted by the mouse.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be an XSS vulerability:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: I think so too. As far as I know you won't even be able to get the window object of the frame let alone do anything with it.